# Errors: check compiler log

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-function

I am learning how to create and call a standalone function. For this reason I use sql developer and create the function there. I wrote the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_bal(acc_no IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS acc_bal NUMBER(11,2);
BEGIN 
   SELECT order_total 
   INTO acc_bal 
   FROM orders 
   WHERE customer_id = acc_no; 
   RETURN(acc_bal); 
 END;
/
```

compiler protocoll displays the following error
[image]

what is wrong with the sql developer?

Comment: Apparently there is no table named `orders` (or your user does not have the privileges to access it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table or view does not exist. run a select query in the same connection to check if the table orders exists or not. else you create the table. or check the connection, whether you are using the correct one.